# Cannot convert parameter 1 from basic_string to String ^

Tags: string, c++-cli, converters

I am trying to use windows form application picturebox method Load. My code to do so is the following:

```
            string image = "image.jpg";
            pictureBox2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(36, 40);
            pictureBox2->Load(image);
            Controls->Add( pictureBox2);
```

However, I am getting the following errors:

```
'void System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox::Load(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' to 'System::String ^'
```

Any idea how can I convert string to String ^?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
std::string image("image.png");
String^ MyString = gcnew String(image.c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

use simply :

```
String ^image = "image.png";
```

`Load` wait a managed string.

Comment: The image name was an exmaple. I am using dirent.h in order to load files from a dir and store them in vector<string>. Is there a change to change vector<string> to vector<String^>?